# How to store a list of dates returned by a subquery so that the list can be used again in postgres

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime

select docdate from jew_sales_edw limit 10;

```
"2022-02-15 00:00:00"
"2022-01-27 00:00:00"
"2022-01-07 00:00:00"
"2022-01-03 00:00:00"
"2021-12-31 00:00:00"
"2022-02-02 00:00:00"
"2021-12-31 00:00:00"
"2021-12-24 00:00:00"
"2022-03-25 00:00:00"
"2022-02-28 00:00:00"
```

I want to store this dates as a list or array in a var so that the variable can be used again in another query

```
UPDATE
    public.transaction_consolidated_temp X
SET
    anniversary_tag = 'Y'
FROM (
    SELECT
        ucic__c,
        cust_unq_id
    FROM
        salesforce.account acc
        INNER JOIN public.mdm_cr_edw mdm ON mdm.ucic::varchar = acc.ucic__c
    WHERE
        DATE_PART('doy', person_date_of_anniversary__c) <= ((
            SELECT
                (docdate::date + integer '21')
            FROM jew_sales_edw
            WHERE
                created_date = CURRENT_DATE))) Y
WHERE
    X.cust_unq_id = Y.cust_unq_id
    AND X.docdate::date = '2022-06-01'::date;
```

this is the query...now select docdate::date + integer '21') from jew_sales_edw where created_date=current_date ---this part returns more than 1 date which has to be stored in a variable right? please help me find a solution

Comment: Why? Instead use it as a subquery: `select * from some table where date in (select docdate from jew_sales_edw limit 10)` or as query in a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-with.html).

Comment: update public.transaction_consolidated_temp X
set anniversary_tag='Y'
from
( select ucic__c,cust_unq_id from salesforce.account acc
inner join public.mdm_cr_edw mdm
 on mdm.ucic::varchar=acc.ucic__c
where DATE_PART('doy',person_date_of_anniversary__c) <= ( (select (docdate::date + integer '21') from jew_sales_edw where created_date=current_date ))) Y
where X.cust_unq_id=Y.cust_unq_id and X.docdate::date='2022-06-01'::date;
this is the query...now select docdate::date + integer '21') from jew_sales_edw where created_date=current_date ---this part returns more than 1 date

Comment: Add the query to the question in a properly formatted form so it is readable.

Comment: I am not seeing how `... DATE_PART('doy', person_date_of_anniversary__c) <= ((SELECT(docdate::date + integer '21')...` is going to work even if it is rewritten? The `DATE_PART` is going to return a `float` value and `docdate::date + integer '21'` is going to return a `date`. They can't be compared. You will need to provide an explanation of what you are trying to achieve? Some example data would be helpful.